# Doctrine2 - add or update without Id

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to check my database for two fields and if they exist to update them and if not to create new.

I want to do that without using an id as post parameter. I was trying to search with `$firstFiled` parameter.

It throws an error

> "Call to a member function setFirstName() on null"

and there are no changes in a database.

My code:

```
public function import($firstName, $lastName)
{
    if($firstName instanceof MyEntity) {

        $new = $this->getMyEntityRepository()->findOneBy([
            'firstName' => $firstName,
            'lastName' => $lastName,
        ]);

    } else {
        $new = new MyEntity();
        $this->em->persist($new);
    }

    $new->setFirstName($firstName);
    $new->setLastName($lastName);
    $this->em->flush();

}
```

Comment: Making new entity works for me. I have a problem updating existing. @jeroen

Answer (score 2):

That code does not make a lot of sense to me; not the condition nor the nested `MyEntity` objects.

What you probably want, is to look for and fetch an object or instantiate a new one if none is found. That is assuming that the first- and last names are not actually instances of that same class.

**Edit:** Note that you need the actual first- and lastnames in order to find the entity in the repository.

So something like:

```
public function import($firstName, $lastName, $newFirstName, $newLastName)
{
    # Get entity from the repository using the current values
    $new = $this->getMyEntityRepository()->findOneBy([
        'firstName' => $firstName,
        'lastName' => $lastName,
    ]);

    # If no entity is found, create a new one
    if(!$new instanceof MyEntity) {
        $new = new MyEntity();
        $this->em->persist($new);
    }

    # Update the existing or new entity with the new values
    $new->setFirstName($newFirstName);
    $new->setLastName($newLastName);
    $this->em->flush();

}
```

By the way, renaming your class and variables to the things they actually represent, would make it easier to spot logical errors like that.

Comment: Thank you as it makes a lot more sense. Your code partly works as it's creating missing entities but not updating existing ones. @jeroen

Comment: @develops Looking back at it, that is actually very logical: If you send in a new firstname or lastname, no entity will be found, so a new one will always be generated. If you want to update based on the name, you need to pass both the current and the new firstnames and lastnames. Then you find the entity using the current name and then set the properties to the new values. I have updated my answer.